# how to make function callable while being able to call funtion inside

Tags: python, object

I am making a game and wanted to make a object class for my objects but also decided to push my self a little and now I hit a road block.

So I want to a function to be callable while being able to use it like a directory.
I don't want the get/set functions to interfere with the get/set classes.

**Example:**

```
obj.position.get()
obj.position.get.x()
```

**Code:**

```
class Object:
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.__x = x
        self.__y = y
        self.__width = width
        self.__height = height
        self.size = self.__Size(self)
        self.position = self.__Position(self)

    class __Size:
        def __init__(self, outer):
            self.__outer = outer
            self.get = self.__get(self.__outer)
            self.set = self.__set(self.__outer)

        # Trying to make the two functions below work without interfering with the __get and __set classes

        def get(self):
            return self.__outer.__width, self.__outer.__height

        def set(self, width, height):
            self.__outer.__width = width
            self.__outer.__height = height

        class __get:
            def __init__(self, outer):
                self.__outer = outer

            def width(self):
                return self.__outer.__width

            def height(self):
                return self.__outer.__height

        class __set:
            def __init__(self, outer):
                self.__outer = outer

            def width(self, width):
                self.__outer.__width = width

            def height(self, height):
                self.__outer.__height = height


    class __Position:
        def __init__(self, outer):
            self.__outer = outer
            self.get = self.__get(self.__outer)
            self.set = self.__set(self.__outer)

        # Trying to make the two functions below work without interfering with the __get and __set classes

        def get(self):
            return self.__outer.__x, self.__outer.__y

        def set(self, x, y):
            self.__outer.__x = x
            self.__outer.__y = y

        class __get:
            def __init__(self, outer):
                self.__outer = outer

            def width(self):
                return self.__outer.__x

            def height(self):
                return self.__outer.__y

        class __set:
            def __init__(self, outer):
                self.__outer = outer

            def x(self, x):
                self.__outer.__x = x

            def y(self, y):
                self.__outer.__y = y
```

Comment: Why do you have a `__get` and `__set` class exactly?

Comment: Class nesting is usually a bad idea, and triple class nesting is worse!

Comment: In order for both `obj.position.get()` and `obj.position.get.x()` to work, `get` just has to be a callable object. That means, whatever type `obj.position.get` has, it should define the `__call__` method to define what `get()` means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is *painfully* complicated. You don't need to have nested classes in order to use composition.

```
class Size:
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height


class Position:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


class Object:
    def __init__(self, size, pos):
        self.size = size
        self.pos = pos

    @classmethod
    def from_scratch(cls, x, y, width, height):
        return cls(Size(x,y), Position(width, height))


obj1 = Object(Size(3, 5), Position(0,0))
obj2 = Object.from_scratch(9, 22, 10, 5)

obj1_location = obj1.position
obj2_size = obj2.size
```

Comment: Honestly don't even remember doing/posting this but i feel like throwing up just from looking at that abomination that I have created ;(